# Displaying GIS Diploma on business card

Tags: education, gis-professional

Is there a standard way to display a GIS diploma for email signatures and/or business cards?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest showing your title as opposed to your diploma, unless you have a doctorate. Suggested titles include *GIS analyst*, *GIS programmer*, *GIS technician*, or a similar, appropriate title. These are suitable whether you currently have a job in the field, or are seeking a GIS job.

The [GIS Certification Institute](http://www.gisci.org) offers certification as a GIS Professional (GISP). Anyone who has been certified by them is entitled/authorized to put "GISP" after their name on emails, etc.